# How to update datagrid xaml MVVM style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I am very new to this MVVM idea, was trying to write my first MVVM application to get my feet wet. Got a little bit of progress but hit road block as I progress. My question is a very basic fundamental one that could be easily addressed with code behind, but it was discouraged to do so as it violates the loose coupling principal I guess. So this is the problem I have:

My Model:

```
public class ToDoItemModel
{
    private DateTime    _TodoDate;
    private string      _TodoDescription;
    private TimeSpan    _TodoTimeSpan;
    private string      _StartTime;

    public string StartTime
    {
        get { return _StartTime; }
        set
        {
            _StartTime = value;
        }
    }
    public TimeSpan ToDoTimeSpan
    {
        get { return _TodoTimeSpan; }
        set
        {
            _TodoTimeSpan = value;
        }
    }        
    public string ToDoDescription
    {
        get { return _TodoDescription; }
        set
        {
            _TodoDescription = value;
        }
    }      
    public DateTime ToDoDate
    {
        get { return _TodoDate; }
        set
        {
            _TodoDate = value;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Date: {0}- Time: {1}- Duration: {2}- Description: {3}",_TodoDate.ToString("d"),_StartTime,_TodoTimeSpan,_TodoDescription);
    }
}
```

My viewModel:

```
    public class ToDoListModelView:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        List<ToDoItemModel> _myModel = new List<ToDoItemModel>();
        public ICommand AddToDo
        {
            get
            {
                return new RelayCommand(addToDo);
            }
        }
        public ToDoListModelView()
        {
            _myModel.Add(new ToDoItemModel() { ToDoDate = DateTime.Now, ToDoDescription = "Testing 1" });
            _myModel.Add(new ToDoItemModel() { ToDoDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), ToDoDescription = "Testing 2" });
        }
        public List<ToDoItemModel> myModel 
        { 
            get { return _myModel; } 
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler!=null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }
        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }

        private void addToDo()
        {
            _myModel.Add(new ToDoItemModel() { ToDoDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2), ToDoDescription = "From Relay Command" });
RaisePropertyChanged("DataGridChanged");
        }
    }
```

The viewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged, and use a class RelayCommand that implements ICommand interface.

My view is:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWPF" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="TestWPF.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Margin="1,0,-1,0" d:DataContext="{d:DesignData /SampleData/ToDoListModelSampleData.xaml}">
        <Button x:Name="AddToDoButton" Content="Add Todo Item&#xA;" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="419,90,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="78" Height="33.04"
                  Command="{Binding AddToDo}"/>
        <DataGrid x:Name="TodoList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                  Margin="33,184,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  RenderTransformOrigin="-0.833,-0.846" Height="108" Width="464" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding myModel}" 
                  Style="{DynamicResource ToDoEntry}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When I hit F5 the application ran and the 2 initial records were displayed.
[image]

However, when I hit the button add, I saw the new record was added internally but the datagrid was not updated. I know the datagrid needs to be refreshed somehow, but I am not sure how to tell the grid to refresh the way MVVM is supposed to handle.
My current code behind is as simple as that:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ToDoListModelView();
    }
}
```

According to the documentation I read from Microsoft site and if I understand it correctly, RaisePropertyChange is supposed to flag a change event occurs, I am just confused how to tie the event to refresh the grid using xaml without any code behind. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `List<ToDoItemModel>` to an `ObservableCollection<ToDoItemModel>`

A `List<T>` does not notify the UI to update when an item gets added or removed from the collection, while an `ObservableCollection<T>` does.

Comment: Thanks Rachel. I have followed your instruction and changed the list to ObservableCollection<T> and it still do not bulge when the button was hit. I have even changed the binding mode to TwoWay as Sageetharan suggested and I still have no luck.

Comment: @user1205746 If you changed `List` to `ObservableCollection` then your code should be correct other than the `RaisePropertyChanged("DataGridChanged");` in `addToDo`, which contains an invalid property name and is not needed. Try removing that, perhaps its causing some internal exception. Do you get any errors or warnings?

Comment: ObservableCollection is the way to go - you don't even need the DataGridChanged property changed event, as the ObservableCollection itself implements INotifyPropertyChanged, and will inform the UI of the collection update. TwoWay binding has no affect in this case, as it is only useful if you need some user input (such as textbox input) to update the model.

Comment: @Rachel: Thank you for looking into my issue. However, I have followed your instruction removing the RaisePropertyChanged but still nothing happenned when I hit the button AddToDo. No error. I have debugged and saw it did actually added an item inside the ObservableCollection, the grid was just not refreshed. Weird...

Comment: I guess what I am still fuzzy is how does the system know that an item was added to the collection? Maybe something happened behind the scene that is transparent to us? We may need to tell the system somehow that the property has changed so that it will refresh itself. But how do we do that? I guess ObservableCollection just tells the system that the Collection could react if something changes, but we have not tell them when the item was added. The system could do that on its own?

Comment: @user1205746 I copied your code into a sample project and it works fine once I change the Lists to ObservableCollections. Do you have anything different in your actual application than what you're showing in code? And an `ObservableCollection` automatically raises CollectionChanged notifications when items get added or removed from it, and the UI knows to update when a change notification is received for any of the bound items, which is why you don't need to do anything custom to refresh the UI.

Comment: @Rachel: Thanks again, Rachel. Let me restart a new solution with the code and see if that is still happening. I have done testing different scenario before asking question here and therefore, it might be something I did before interfering and caused the side effect. I am very new to the MVVM stuff and it might be some other codes accidentally left in there that messed thing up.

Comment: @Rachel: That is very interesting. I created a new solution and copied the exact code I had on this question, changed List to ObservableCollection and it works! I have to go back and compare what was the junk inside my old code that has interfered with the operation and confused me for so long! Many thanks! Just changing from List to ObservableCollection is sufficient, nothing else needed!!

Comment: @Rachel: Quick question, everything is fine after List was replaced by ObservableCollection. Only one thing that I still do not quite understand is when I made ToDoListModelView a normal class by removing INofifyPropertyChange, the app is still running as expected when I hit AddToDo button and the datagrid was updated. Why the modelview does not need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged as I thought?

Comment: @user1205746 You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` if a property on the class changes to a different value, and something (like the UI) needs to be notified of this change. For example, if your `MyModel` class got set to a new value somehow, then you'd need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. You're not actually changing the value of the property though, you're only changing the data inside the property, so `INotifyPropertyChanged` is not needed.

Comment: I see. The data inside the property vs the value of the property of a class. I'll keep that in mind... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to Use **Binding** **Mode** [`TwoWay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) also change your List to ObservableCollection

An ObservableCollection will notify the UI when a record is added or removed.

```
ObservableCollection<ToDoItemModel> _myModel = new ObservableCollection<ToDoItemModel>();
public ICommand AddToDo
{
get
  {
  return new RelayCommand(addToDo);
  }
}
public ToDoListModelView()
{
 _myModel.Add(new ToDoItemModel() { ToDoDate = DateTime.Now, ToDoDescription = "Testing 1" });
 _myModel.Add(new ToDoItemModel() { ToDoDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), ToDoDescription = "Testing 2" });
}
public ObservableCollection <ToDoItemModel> myModel 
{ 
 get { return _myModel; } 
}
```

**XAML:**

```
  <DataGrid x:Name="TodoList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                      Margin="33,184,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                      RenderTransformOrigin="-0.833,-0.846" Height="108" Width="464" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding myModel,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                      Style="{DynamicResource ToDoEntry}"/>
```

Comment: I have followed your suggestion, but I still have no luck.. not sure what else I have missed. With 2 waybinding, I got an error saying can not bind readonly, I have removed the readonly from myModel.

Comment: `TwoWay` binding does not matter in this case. `TwoWay` is needed in cases where the UI changes the bound property to a different value, and this does not happen with an `ItemsSource` binding.

Answer (score 0):

Use ObservableCollection instead of Lists (as it was told above), and set
`UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` in the XAML.

**CODE**:

`<DataGrid x:Name="TodoList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
Margin="33,184,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
RenderTransformOrigin="-0.833,-0.846" Height="108" Width="464" 
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=myModel,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }" 
Style="{DynamicResource ToDoEntry}"/>`

Comment: The `UpdateSourceTrigger` is only needed if the UI is updating the source property to a new value, and this does not happen with the `ItemsSource` binding.